# Como hacer que el usuario ponga el dato en una posicion especifica de una matriz?

Tags: java, matrices

quisiera que me ayudaran un poco con este problema

ya tengo algo del codigo pero parece que esta mal, tambien quiere que ingrese el usuario en una posicion especifica de la matriz

aqui el codigo que ya tengo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//ultima fecha de modificacion: 02/05/2020

public class Matriz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada =new Scanner (System.in);
    int matriz [][], nFilas, nCol;

    nFilas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el Numero de Filas"));
    nCol = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el Numero de Columnas"));

    matriz =new int [nFilas][nCol]; 
    System.out.println("Digite la Matriz: ");
    for(int i=0;i<nFilas;i++){
      for( int j=0;j<nCol;j++){
        System.out.println("Matriz ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");
        matriz [i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
      }   
    }

    System.out.println("\nLa Matriz es: ");
    for(int i=0;i<nFilas;i++){ //numero de filas
      for(int j=0;j<nCol;j++){ //numero de columnas
         System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: aca el codigo que ya tengo

Comment: No uso java, pero en la matriz[i][j] en lugar de j o i tenes que pasarle la posicion que quieras en numero mediante una variable.

Comment: Exacto tienes que pedir la posicion y el dato a ingresar, despues imprimir el dato que quiere el usuario (tiene que darte la ubicacion i,j del dato que quiere ver), finalmente esta bien lo ultimo de imprimir toda la matriz

Comment: es lo que no logro resolver, como hacer que pida una ubicacion especifica

Comment: no entiendo tu problema... sile pedis al usuario la fila y la columna cualseria el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

christian, he desarrollado un codigo guia, el cual se basa en el enunciado, en el cual, se debe colocar un menu, y se deben realizar operaciones, en el encontraras, como se consultan los indices para cambiar valores en la matriz, y mostrarlos dependiendo de como quiera el usuario, ademas de mantener el programa corriendo hasta que el usuario lo pida, al codigo le faltan modificaciones para que cumpla con todo lo expuesto en el enunciado.
Debo mencionar que he tenido tu codigo desarrollado en cuenta, y que no he tomado en cuanta validaciones como si la opcion del menu ingresada por el usuario esta en un rango permitido.

**CODIGO**

```
boolean continuar=true;
                int opcionMenu
                while(continuar){
                    //Imprimir el menu
                    System.out.println("Menu");
                    System.out.println("1. Ingresar dato a la matriz.");
                    System.out.println("2. Consultar dato de la matriz.");
                    System.out.println("3. Imprimir toda la matriz.");
                    //Obtener decision del usuario sobre que opcion desea realizar.
                    System.out.println("Opcion:");
                    opcionMenu=entrada.nextInt();
                    //Estas variables se usaran, dependiendo de la opcion que el usuario tome en el menu
                    int fila, columna,sino;
                    switch(opcionMenu){
                        case 1:
                            //Se ingresara un dato a la matriz, pero primero necesitamos la posicion!!
                            //Pedimos la fila
                            System.out.println("Ingresa la posicion de la fila:");
                            fila=entrada.nextInt();
                            //Pedimos la columna
                            System.out.println("Ingresa la posicion de la columna:");
                            columna=entrada.nextInt();
                            //Pedimos el dato
                            System.out.println("Ingresa el dato a colocar:");
                            //e inmediatamente lo colocamos en el arreglo
                            matriz[fila][columna]=entrada.nextInt();
                            //imprimimos mensaje de confirmacion
                            System.out.println("Dato en la posicion "+fila+","+columna+" cambiado exitosamente!");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            //Se ingresara un dato a la matriz, pero primero necesitamos la posicion!!
                            //Pedimos la fila
                            System.out.println("Ingresa la posicion de la fila:");
                            fila=entrada.nextInt();
                            //Pedimos la columna
                            System.out.println("Ingresa la posicion de la columna:");
                            columna=entrada.nextInt();
                            //Mostramos el dato
                            System.out.println("Dato en la posicion ("+fila+","+columna+")="+matriz[fila][columna]);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //Coloca el mismo codigo que tienes de imprimir la matriz completa
                            //AQUI
                            break;
                        default:
                            // Si no se ingresa un numero del 1 al 3
                            System.out.println("Opcion no reconozida!!!");
                            break;
                    }
                    //Se pregunta si se desea salir del programa
                    System.out.println("Desea salir?");
                    System.out.println("1.Si");
                    System.out.println("2.No");
                    //Se pide 1 o 2 para saber si se desea continuar
                    sino=entrada.nextInt();
                    //Si responde 1 se debe terminar la ejecucion
                    continuar=sino!=1;
                }
                System.out.println("Ejecucion terminada");
```

El codigo tiene comentado, para que es cada parte del mismo y el mismo debe ser insertado al final del codigo que ya tienes.

Comment: gracias, me ayudo de mucho para guiarme, seguire practicando.

Comment: dale, animo y mucha suerte